# Transform JSON into correct format to put in Morris Bar Chart plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, morris.js

I'm using the Morris Bar Chart plugin. [You can see an example here](http://jsbin.com/uzosiq/258/embed?javascript,live).

The correct data format to insert into the chart is the following:

```
data: [
    { y: '2006', a: 100, b: 90 },
    { y: '2007', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2008', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2009', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2010', a: 50,  b: 40 },
    { y: '2011', a: 75,  b: 65 },
    { y: '2012', a: 100, b: 90 }
  ],
```

I want to fill that info but with ajax request to PHP.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getchart.php',
    success: function(content){

        console.log(content); // Native return

        var element = [];   
        var json    = JSON.parse(content);

        for(var i = 0; i <= json.length - 1; i++){
            element[i] = {y: json[i][0].month, a: json[i][0].total};
        }

        console.log(element);
    }
});
```

I've accomplish the request successfully but I do need to convert the json I get from ajax to the format that morris chart needs.

```
[[{"total":1,"Month":7,"description":"Started"},
{"total":1,"Month":6,"description":"Started"}],
[{"total":3,"Month":6,"description":"Started"}]]
```

The code above is what the variable `content` output. The problem here is that one index contains 2 sub-indexes and the other index contains only one sub-index:

**Index 1:**

```
[{"total":1,"Month":7,"description":"Started"},
 {"total":1,"Month":6,"description":"Started"}],
```

And the second index only contains one sub-index

**Index 2:**

```
[{"total":3,"Month":6,"description":"Started"}]],
```

This happens because I'm pushing two different arrays into one in PHP.

```
$AN = $chart->chartAN(); // Apresentation and Negociation
$AC = $chart->chartAC(); // Accomplished

$final = array($AN, $AC);

echo json_encode($final);
```

And, btw, the output from both of functions is the same:

```
while($query->fetch()){     
  $rows[] = array("total" => $total, "month" => $month, "description" => $type);
}
```

Currently, the `console.log(element)` returns me:

```
[Object, Object];
    > 0: Object
        a: 1
        y: 7

    > 1: Object
        a: 3
        y: 6
```

My final result I would like it to be something like:

```
element: [
          { y: 'April', a: value_from_chartAN, b: value_from_chartAC },
          { y: 'May',   a: value_from_chartAN, b: value_from_chartAC },
         ],
```

**EDIT**: To clarify the question (because I know isn't that simple).

I would like my output to be:

```
element: [
              { y: month_from_database, a: value_from_chartAN, b: value_from_chartAC },
              { y: month_from_database, a: value_from_chartAN, b: value_from_chartAC },
             ],
```

Since `value_from_chartAN` or `value_from_chartAC` might be null, it must add the number 0.
If you look at the example of Morris: http://jsbin.com/uzosiq/258/embed?javascript,live

The year correspond to my Month, the blue bar to the `value_from_chartAN` and the gray bar to `value_from_chartAC`.

Comment: To flatten the returned json array in the browser -- to get rid of the two index problem -- see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript

Comment: I dont see where the value for `b:` in your expected output is supposed to come from, and the value for `y:` should logically be a year (2014) yet you want it to be a month (April)? Please edit you question to clarify

Comment: I've just updated my topic.

Comment: @user3355243 OK, ill update my answer with a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that your PHP return values (your JSON that you will send) is not on the same structure as needed by the Bar chart. You need to flatten it first. From there you code should work fine. [**Sample Fiddle**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/coeEem)

Consider this example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['get_values'])) {
    // replication of your data
    $final = '[[{"total":1,"Month":7,"description":"Started"},{"total":1,"Month":6,"description":"Started"}],[{"total":3,"Month":6,"description":"Started"}]]';
    $final = json_decode($final, true);
    $new_final = array();
    // simple flattening
    foreach($final as $value) {
        foreach($value as $sub_value) {
            $new_final[] = $sub_value;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($new_final);
    exit;
}

?>

<div id="bar-example"></div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.oesmith.co.uk/morris-0.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        url: document.URL, // getchart.php
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {get_values: true},
        success: function(response) {
            Morris.Bar({
                element: 'bar-example',
                data: response,
                xkey: 'description',
                ykeys: ['Month', 'total'],
                labels: ['Month', 'Total']
            });
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: For what I've tried so far it seems to work. But I'm going to lunch now and when I come back, I'll test in a better way your code. After that I'll come here and tell you. Thanks.

Comment: @user3355243 okay, you can check the fiddle above and just fiddle around it. sure no problem

Comment: Ok, I've made a few changes, but in the end worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You control the data sent from the server, so make sure its in the correct format before sending it - simply merge the php arrays into one, and set the correct header:

```
$final = array_merge($AN, $AC);
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($final);
```

Now you have the exact format you require returned to your ajax function, no further js processing required:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'getchart.php',
    success: function(content){
        console.log(content); // Native return is as required

    }
});
```

EDIT as per your clarification. The solution is still to send the correct data from php, but the code is a little more complicated:

```
//simulated calls to your functions, based on your posted data
$an = json_decode('[{"total":1,"Month":7,"description":"Started"}, {"total":1,"Month":6,"description":"Started"}]', true);
$ac = json_decode('[{"total":3,"Month":6,"description":"Started"}]', true);


//1st create an array from the $ac data that uses the month value as the key, 
//so we can check if  any month is contained in the array simply:    
$ac_new=array();
foreach($ac as $item){
    $month = $item['Month'];
    $ac_new[$month] = $item['total'];
}
//array to hold are final data
$data = array();

foreach($an as $item){
    $y = $item['Month'];
    $a = $item['total'];

    //if there is a value for this month in ac_new array, set $b to its value
    //and then remove the element from the ac_new array, else set $b = 0
    if(isset($ac_new[$y])){
        $b = $ac_new[$y];
        unset($ac_new[$y]);
    }else{
        $b = 0;
    }
    $data[] = array('y' => $y, 'a' => $a, 'b' => $b);
}

//if there any elements left in $ac_new then they are for months 
//not included in $an array, so value for a must be 0
if(count($ac_new)>0){
    foreach($ac_new as $key => $value){
        $data[] = array('y' => $key, 'a' => 0, 'b' => $value);
    }
}

//return correctly formatted data
header('Content-Type: application/json');    
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for (i guess). How can I have the output that I told in the end of the post?

Comment: @user3355243 Why, it dont understand?

Comment: I've tried your solution but I don't get how it's going ot help me reaching that desire output.

Comment: @user3355243 Ok, i see what you mean - your question was a little confusing and i missed just how you want to format the data. I will edit with a solution soon

Comment: Your code works and it is what I was trying when I created the topic. But I was doing that same code in Javascript instead of PHP. However, the solution of @Kevinabelita is way shorter and I do believe better. Still, +1 for every help and interest.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();

include("../phpfiles/include/Config.php"); //db connect


$dbc = @mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);

if(!$dbc)
{
    trigger_error('Could not connect to MySql:'. mysqli_connect_error());
}
$query = "SELECT dateandtime,sum(grandtotal) FROM bb_pos.bb_bill
group by MONTH(dateandtime), YEAR(dateandtime) order by dateandtime DESC limit 12 "; // last 12 month in descending order
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
$cart = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $date = $row['dateandtime'];
    $time=strtotime($date);
    $month=date("F",$time);
    $year=date("Y",$time);
    array_push($cart,array(
    'period'=>$month." ".$year,
    'SALE'=>$row['sum(grandtotal)']));

}

echo json_encode($cart);
mysqli_close($dbc);
?>  

<body>
<div class="x_content1">
   <div id="graph_bar_group" style="width:100%; height:280px;"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$.getJSON('morrisdata.php', function(data) 
    {
        var date = data;
        function custom_sort(a, b) {
        return new Date(a.period).getTime() - new Date(b.period).getTime();
        }   
        date.sort(custom_sort); // convert the last 12 months in ascending order

    //var product_name = data.name;
        Morris.Bar({
            element: 'graph_bar_group',
            data: data,
            xkey: ['period'],
            ykeys: ['SALE'],
            labels: ['SALE'],
            hideHover: 'auto',
            resize: true,
            parseTime: false,
            xLabelAngle: 60

        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Could you please add some context on how this code help solves the OP's issue? Code block dumps, without explanation, are generally frowned upon

Comment: I dont know about OP's issue?

Comment: Are you looking for help? If so, you need to post a new question, not an answer on an old one. I would also recommend writing about what the issue you have is.

Comment: i m not asking new question. its the solution for those who want to show real data on Morris Bar Chart. As i haven't found any solution for Morris bar Chart. After searching so much for google and stack overflow then i m able to make it work for me. so i want to share with other people

Comment: If this doesn't specifically address this OP's problem, it shouldn't be an answer here. Instead, write your own question and post this answer there (self-answer Q&A is perfectly fine).